# Classifying the irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups

I need help with the following problem:

> Suppose $n$ is some positive integer, and $n|p-1$.  Classify all irreducible representations of  $$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}.$$

I am not sure where to start,

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Start by constructing many representations. For example, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a quotient of your group, and its representations are well-known.

Comment: Also, you did not state which action is implied for the semi-direct product.

Answer (score 14):

I assume that you are talking about a faithful action of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. First, there are the obvious lifts of the irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$. For the rest:

**Exercise 1:** The induction of a non-trivial character of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$ is irreducible.

**Exercise 2:** When are two such inductions isomorphic?

**Exercise 3:** Now count the sums of squares of the degrees of the characters that you get this way.

I have to say that this is rather tough homework if you were not given any of these hints. But with them, you should be able to do the rest yourself.

*Edit:* More generally, suppose that $G=A\rtimes H$ where $A$ is abelian. Then all irreducible characters of $G$ are obtained as follows. $H$ acts on the irreducible characters of $A$ by $(h\cdot\chi)(a) = \chi(h^{-1}ah)$. Let $\chi$ be a linear character of $A$. Extend it to $S_\chi=A\rtimes \text{Stab}_H(\chi)$, where $\text{Stab}_H(\chi)\leq H$ is the stabiliser of $\chi$ in $H$ under the above action, by setting $\chi(as) = \chi(a)$ for $a\in A,s\in \text{Stab}_H(\chi)$. Let $\rho$ be an irreducible character of $\text{Stab}_H(\chi)$, lift it to an irreducible character of $S_\chi$. Then $\text{Ind}_{G/S_\chi}(\chi\otimes \rho)$ is an irreducible character of $G$ and they all arise in this way. I will leave it to you to determine when two such inductions are isomorphic, so as not to spoil the homework exercise.

Note that your question is a special case of this, since $H=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ acts faithfully on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and therefore also on its irreducible characters. Thus, $\text{Stab}_H(\chi)$ is trivial in your case, whenever $\chi$ is non-trivial.

Comment: Hi Alex wahat is the degree of these irreducible characters?

Comment: @SvenWirsing: In the specific situation of the OP, they are 1- and $n$-dimensional. In the general situation of my Edit, they are $($dim $\rho\cdot \#$orbit$_H(\chi))$-dimensional. That just follows from the fact that under induction, the dimension of a representation grows by the index of the subgroup that you are inducing from.

Comment: I investigate the sum of degrees of the irreducible characters. In the example here the derived group is $A$ and hence there are $n$ linear characters. Using the fact that $np$ is the sum of squares of the irr. characters I see that there are $\frac{p-1}{n}$ irr. of degree n. Hence the sum is $p-1+n$\\ Using your construction above one get from the trivial character of A and the n linear characters from H exactly n irr. characters of degree 1. From the other $p-1$ irreducibles of $A$ we get $p-1$ induced irr. of degree $n$ as the stabilizer is trivial in this cases. Where is my fault?

Comment: You need to do what I labelled as Exercise 2.

Comment: @AlexB. Is there any reference for the construction that you have provided or is it too stnadrad? I am an outsider to group theory so I don't know the standard results...

Comment: @AlexB. I have a follow up question. What will happen if the group A in your answer is not abelian? Will $\mbox{Ind}_{G/S_\chi}(\chi\otimes\rho)$ be still irreducible?

Comment: @Krishnarjun For a reference, see Serre's Linear Representations of Finite Groups, Section 8.2. If $A$ is not abelian, then things become more complicated. The first thing that breaks down is that you cannot, in general, just "extend" a character of $A$ to a character of $A\rtimes {\rm Stab}_H(\chi)$ by declaring that the extended character should act trivially on the stabiliser. This won't be a character, in general. As an example, you can think about $G=Q_8\rtimes C_3$ with $C_3$ acting as the outer automorphism $i\mapsto j\mapsto k\mapsto i$, which happens to be isomorphic to ...

Comment: ...  ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$. There is no representation of $G$ that reduces to the standard $2$-dimensional representation of $Q_8$ and to the trivial representation of $C_3$, even though $C_3$ clearly stabilises the standard character of $Q_8$ (it is, after all, the only $2$-dimensional character of $Q_8$).

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at Weintraub - "Representation theory of finite group" in the section Mackey Machine. They give the right tool for exactly studying the irreducible representation of a semidirect product $H \rtimes G$, where $H$ is abelian.

In fact, the Mackey Machine holds in greater generality for an exact sequence of locally compact groups
$ 1 \rightarrow H \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow 1,$
with some mild conditions on $H$ (being type 1).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a place to start, although not a complete solution by any means. Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $\mathbb{Z}/n\subset G$ and $\mathbb{Z}\subset G$.

If we restrict a representation to one of these two subgroups, it will split as a direct sum of irreducibles, and because the subgroups are abelian, this means that we can find a basis of eigenvectors for the action of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ (or a basis of eigenvectors for the action of $\mathbb{Z}/n$).

Suppose that $\omega$ is a $p$th root of unity, and that $v$ is a vector such that $k.v=\omega^k v$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}/p$.  If $j\in \mathbb{Z}/n$, then how does $k$ act on $j.v$?  Use the commutation relations that you know you have in $G$ between elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p$