# Question about a question (irreducible representations of a semidirect product)

Tags: representation-theory, finite-groups

In the question

[Classifying the irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38571/classifying-the-irreducible-representations-of-mathbbz-p-mathbbz-rtimes-m/38589#38589)

the author is talking about irreducible representations of a semi-direct product. Does he mean representations over $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{F}_p, \ldots$? Or would the way to construct them be the same?

I'm not sure if it is allowed to re-ask a question. If not. I'm sorry.

Comment: Over a field ofcharacteristic $p,$ the normal subgroup of order $p$ will act trivially, so you are looking at the irreducible representations of the cyclic group of order $n$. Over fields of other characteristics, one can proceed via Cliffords theorem in a reasonably uniform way, although when the characteristic divides $n$ the theory is a little different, but not too significantly.

Comment: The old answer is talking about $\mathbb{C}$, though the ideas can be applied more generally.

Comment: Are there more literature which refers to irred. representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ for a prime $q$? I could not find anything in the library.

Comment: guest look up [modular representation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_representation_theory).

Answer (score 0):

As Jack Schmidt said: "The old answer is talking about $\mathbb C$, though the ideas can be applied more generally."

(It seems this question has been answered in the comments; in order for the question to be marked as *answered*, I copied the answer above and made this CW.)