# Irreducible representations of finite lamplighter group

Tags: representation-theory, wreath-product

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}_n$ be the finite lamplighter group. What are the irreducible representations of $G$ - can anyone provide a clear reference?

Austin, Naor and Valette list representations of $G$ here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4662 (page 4), however, it seems to me that they are not all irreducible (dimension count gives $\sum_{\rho} d_{\rho}^2> |G|$).

Answer (score 2):

One can explicitly describe all the irreducible characters of a semi-direct products by an abelian group. This is done in Serre's rep theory book, Chapter II, Section 8.2, or [here in the edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38571/classifying-the-irreducible-representations-of-mathbbz-p-mathbbz-rtimes-m/38589#38589).